# How many female players participated in the european indivdual championship?

Tags: tournament

The female players, I found out in the european individual championship, are

WGM Aleksandra Goryachkina
 WGM Maria Manakova
 WIM Olga Vasiliev
 WIM Camelia-Adriana Ciobanu

Did any other female players participate ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the [final rankings here](http://chess-results.com/tnr157274.aspx?lan=1&art=1&rd=11&fed=ENG&turdet=YES&flag=30&wi=984&zeilen=99999) to get a list of all participants. You could then check the names against [the FIDE ratings website](http://ratings.fide.com/) which would tell you the gender of the player.

A quick glance through the list shows these additional female players (probably not exhaustive)

Shlomit Vardi

Limor Altshul

Sophia Toporkova

Michal Lahav

Comment: Please check the players, then I accept your answer.